# How to setup a high performance parity RPC service?

Tags: optimization, hosting, aws, tuning

I'd like to provide the RPC service from a parity daemon hosted in EC2. There're multiple options regarding the instance type, if it's for production, should I choose "compute optimized" or "storage optimized"?

Is there anything system settings to tune to optimize the performance?

Any suggestions and insights are appreciated!

Comment: Good question.
Anyone can help with config.toml?